# Is it possible include javascript in url link?

Tags: javascript, url

What I want to do is when I reach the site the link guide to, then execute some javascript

So is it possible include javascript code in url link, or I can attach a javascript file link after the url?

**Edited:**
for instance, when the someone reach my twitter site, then execute some js, the js could click the "follow" button automaticly

Comment: Explain what you mean by "reach the site"

Comment: This smells like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/133242). What are you actually trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: So you just want to run some JS code when people go to your site? Just add it in the body onload event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  It would be a huge security risk to allow that.

Answer (score 2):

**You need to see this: [Bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet)**

> A bookmarklet is unobtrusive script written in JavaScript and stored
>   as the URL of a bookmark in a web browser or as a hyperlink on a web
>   page.

Answer (score 0):

no you can not add javascript code into url link.